# sorting on the basis on a column not alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting

I have a bean called vulnerability. It is having a column "severity".

```
private String severity;
```

Severity can hold string value High,Medium and Low. Now whenever sorting of this bean on the basis of severity column is done it happens alphabetically i.e. High,Low and Medium. But i want the sorting to happen high,medium, low when descending and low, medium,high when ascending. 
I was seeing comparator to make this custom sorting but it needs to cover lots of cases. Isn't their any other way?

Comment: Well, 3 cases are not *lot of cases* IMHO. Why don't you simply make your bean implement Comparable?

Comment: use enum instead of String

Comment: @sp00m actually there are 9 options

Comment: Use enum: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149671/compare-java-enum-values

Answer (score 2):

You can (and should) use an enum - not a String nor a int:

```
enum Severity {
    LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
    List<Severity> lst = new ArrayList<Severity>();
    lst.add(Severity.MEDIUM);
    lst.add(Severity.LOW);
    lst.add(Severity.HIGH);
    for (Severity s : lst)
        System.out.println("s = " + s);

    Collections.sort(lst);

    System.out.println();

    for (Severity s : lst)
        System.out.println("s = " + s);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
s = MEDIUM
s = LOW
s = HIGH

s = LOW
s = MEDIUM
s = HIGH
```

**EDIT**

Since the OP says he can't modify the usage of Strings, we can map the strings into a comparable values:

```
static Map<String, Integer> severities = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

static {
    severities.put("LOW",1);
    severities.put("MEDIUM",2);
    severities.put("HIGH",3);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    lst.add("MEDIUM");
    lst.add("LOW");
    lst.add("HIGH");
    for (String s : lst)
        System.out.println("s = " + s);

    Collections.sort(lst, new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String a1, String a2) {
            Integer v1 = severities.get(a1);
            Integer v2 = severities.get(a2);
            return v1.compareTo(v2);
        }
    });

    System.out.println();

    for (String s : lst)
        System.out.println("s = " + s);

}
```

and if you want to order the items in descending order you can sort and then reverse:

```
    Collections.sort(lst);
    Collections.reverse(lst);
```

Comment: How can you sort descending and ascending using enum?

Comment: Enums are comparable, every enum value has ordinal() method returning int.

Comment: my issue is i am not authorised to change the bean. Cannot change type from string to enum.

Comment: You can make an enum describing possible values and use Enum.valueOf() to convert from string to enum in Comparator

Comment: @white A tip for better life (from "Effective Java" by Bloch): `Never derive a value associated with an enum from its ordinal; store it in an instance field instead`

Comment: Why "never derive a value associated with an enum from its ordinal" if you are not intereseted in the value, and only in their order? It *does* make sense... yes, you can outgrow it, but then is when you add your field.

Comment: Absolutely true, but it does NOT say that you should never use ordinal() on enum's value. A tip for better life, take a look at java source code, f.ex. compareTo in http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Enum.java.html

Comment: @white yes he actually says that on the previous paragraph. Then he provides 3 examples that show why doing so (using `ordinal()`) could make it become a "maintenance nightmare" (in his own words). Second, the fact that `enum` class itself using its ordinals is perfectly fine, it's *you* who shouldn't use it ;)

Comment: @white Here's an [*appetizer*](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/25234/577468/4h5ucfN58QJ4CJU/Screen%20Shot%202014-07-17%20at%202.09.06%20AM.png)

Comment: Once again, I do not propose you to use ordinal() to derive associated value, instead, according to the question, I just say, that this method could be used for sorting. In fact, if you look inside java sources, this is actually used in compareTo method of Enum.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implicit `compareTo` operator defined on `enum`s, which [takes their declaration order to mean "smaller than"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo%28E%29). *No additional code is needed.*

```
enum Severity { Low, Medium, High }

Low.compareTo(High);   // returns -1
Medium.compareTo(Low); // returns 1
```

However, note that the names of the enum constants will be those printed by `toString()` (and therefore visible to users if you echo enums directly) - if you want to use different internal and external names, possibly to uphold code conventions (say, all-caps-constants), then you will need to add an enum constructor and override the enum's `toString` method to use the passed-in constructor attribute.

---

**If you cannot use enums, and you cannot change your bean**

Then build a Comparator for it:

```
public class SeverityComparator implements Comparator<String> {
     private int direction;

     public SeverityComparator(boolean reverse) {
         this.direction = reverse ? -1 : 1;
     }

     private int severity(String s) {
         if (s.equals("Low")) { // you really should have constants for the values...
             return 0;
         } else if (s.equals("Medium")) {
             return 1;
         } else if (s.equals("High")) {
             return 2;
         } else {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a severity: " + s);
         }
     }

     @Override
     public int compareTo(String other) {
         return direction * (severity(this) - severity(other));
     }
}
```

Use as

```
Collections.sort(listOfSeverities, new SeverityComparator(false)); // ascending
Collections.sort(listOfSeverities, new SeverityComparator(true)); // descending
```

Answer (score 0):

@alfasin answer is correct but i would suggest using guava's Ordering:

```
    import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import com.google.common.collect.Ordering;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;
import java.util.List;

public class SeveritySortTest {

    private static final List<Severity> SEVERITY_LIST = ImmutableList.copyOf(Severity.values());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Ordering<Severity> severityOrdering = Ordering.natural().onResultOf(new Function<Severity, Integer>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Integer apply(@Nullable Severity input) {
                return input.getSeverity();
            }
        });

        List<Severity> sortedAscending = severityOrdering.sortedCopy(SEVERITY_LIST);
        List<Severity> sortedDescending = severityOrdering.reverse().sortedCopy(SEVERITY_LIST);

    }


    enum Severity {
        LOW(1), MEDIUM(2), HIGH(3);

        private int severity;

        Severity(int s) {
            severity = s;
        }

        int getSeverity() {
            return severity;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the Guava package add? including an overriden CompareTo in the enum would avoid including an extra dependency

Comment: For me Guava is a must-have library in every project so i did not consider it as an extra dependency. If you have not used Guava i suggest you to give it a chance

Comment: And also apache commons, and so many others... everyone has their standard dependencies, but they are generally different for each group

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution:**

Collections.sort(recommendations, new Comparator() {

```
            private int priority(String s) {
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Low")) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Medium")) {
                    return 2;
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("High")) {
                    return 3;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int compare(Recommendation o1, Recommendation o2) {
                return -1 * (priority(o1.getPriority()) - priority(o2.getPriority()));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DB to do this through JPA/Hibernate you could create a sort expression based on a simple case statement, assuming your entity is called Case:

```
Expression exp = criteriaBuilder.selectCase(root.get(Case_.priority)).when("High", 1).when("Medium", 2).otherwise(3);
queryBuilder.orderBy(orderDir.isAscending() ? criteriaBuilder.asc(exp) : criteriaBuilder.desc(exp));
```

Using case statements in an order by clause isn't great for performance, but solves it. Works with Oracle.