# Sorting Strings in order of importance

Tags: java, sorting

So I am working on a set of code that utilizes the users highest level of earned education and return true if the new degree is better and false otherwise.

I need to write a class that compares the new degree that was entered to the already set highest degree. The order of importance is: anything else < BA < BS < MA < MS < MBA. I did a little bit of searching but could not seem to find anything that answered my question to my satisfaction. Is there an easy way to organize the degrees in order of importance? Or is it possible to just do:

```
   if (newDegree > highestDegree){
      return true; 
   }else{
      return false; 
   }
```

and set the newDegree and highestDegree to be variables. I have spent most of my coding time using python and am kinda new to java so forgive me if there is a simple answer to this.

Comment: Did you try to run the code you posted?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007108/java-sorting-based-on-enum-constants

Comment: You're missing `return` on your `else` clause.

Comment: You could try using Enum class and assign integer value to each enum attributes and compare the integer value [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149671/compare-java-enum-values)

Comment: @Luminous_Dev no need to assign an integer value. Enums are intrinsically comparable. Just declare them in the right order.